# Convergence of the complex sequence $c_{n}=\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i) \right )^{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I got an exercise to determine the sequence converges or not, $c_{n}=\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i) \right )^{n}\in \mathbb{C}$.

I re-wrote it to
$$c_{n}=\left |c_{n}  \right |e^{i\theta}=1^{n}\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right )$$

Since $1^{n}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, thus $c_{n}\to (1/\sqrt{2})+(i/\sqrt{2})$ as $n\to\infty$. I would say this sequence converges - but the answer says it SHOULD diverge. I tried to analyze it in different ways and did my best to understand it - but I could not understand it completely. Could you please explain why?

(**NOTE**: You might have noticed the mistake I have made in this expression. After having found the answer I have been looking for - I let this post to be original without editing it otherwise the comments/answers below would be senseless. Thank you for helping me!)

Comment: What is the modulus of $ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i) \ $ ? What is its _argument_? You've raised it to the $ \ n$ th power incorrectly...

Comment: #RecklessReckoner: The modulos is $1$ and its argument is $\pi/4$. Should it have been $c_{n}=|c_{n}|e^{in\theta}$?

Comment: As you've notated that line in your post, yes.  See also the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the form $re^{i\theta}$ we find that $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ since $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|=1$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Rerwiting $c_{n}$ using the above makes the sequence become:
$$
c_{n}=e^{in\frac{\pi}{4}},
$$ 
which rotates around the circle with period $8$ and hence does not converge.

Note for example that $c_{8n}=1$ and $c_{8n+4}=-1$.

Comment: I understand now why I couldn't understand this exercise - because I made a "small" mistake. Thanks for showing your method and for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help you understand.

Answer (score 1):

$c_n= e^{i \frac{\pi n}{4}}$ which clearly diverges.